# NopCommerce - What's the proper connection string for a SQL Server on a domain?

Tags: connection-string, nopcommerce

I had this up and running on a Dell T110 running Windows Server 2012 Essentials.  Unfortunately, as I found out, Server 2012 Essentials will reboot itself every 5 days if it's not a Primary Domain Controller.  So, with my limited knowledge of servers, I converted it to a PDC.  Now, every time I try to load my website, it goes to the Install page.

After a bit of searching and trial/error, I discovered that the likely culprit was that it couldn't find the database anymore.  Settings.txt is in the AppData folder, I checked that too.  The only thing I could think of is that my SQL Server changed a little.  For instance, in SQL Server, the server name is now listed as:

```
MICKEY (SQL Server 11.0.2100 - PDC\Admin)
```

PDC is the name I gave to my domain.  Would that impact my connection string in Settings.txt?  If so, what do I need to change my connection string to?

I'm using NopCommerce 3.8 if that matters.  And the strangest part is that it seems to work fine in the development environment, which uses the same database.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's on the domain or not, connection string won't change. The security to connect might be different, but that's a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

As David stated, domain doesn't matter. But what matter is changed in sequel server(name or credentials)

For instance, before connection string was:

```
DataProvider: sqlserver
DataConnectionString: Data Source=DELL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Nop380;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=password
```

Now, you have changed DELL to PDC, then you have to change the `Data Source` in connection string.

```
DataProvider: sqlserver
DataConnectionString: Data Source=PDC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Nop380;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=password
```

Hope this helps!